# OSX 10.10 and Eclipse Luna. Own App crashes when started from inside Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I have updated to Yosemite today and have much problems with java. Most java applications crashes on start but after reinstall of the old Mac-Java 1.6 that problem seems to be solved.

But I have an other big problem. When I start Eclipse Luna and build my own Java application and start this application with the run button in Eclipse, it crashes with the following report:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _CGContextSetAllowsAcceleration
  Referenced from: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_35-b10-428.jdk/Contents/Libraries/libawt.jnilib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices

dyld: Symbol not found: _CGContextSetAllowsAcceleration
  Referenced from: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_35-b10-428.jdk/Contents/Libraries/libawt.jnilib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
```

When I export the app as .jar file and start it from outside eclipse eveything works fine.

Do you have any solution how I can fix this? Otherwise I must reinstall Mavericks to be productive tomorrow.

Answer (score 17):

After I re-installed using http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572 I had two JDK 1.6 versions in the system.

1. /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_65-b14-462.jdk/
2. /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/   (1.6.0_65-b14-466.1)

1 (-462) was used by Eclipse. It gave the same error as you have.

2 (-466) was used from command line. That one worked.

So I changed the "Installed JREs" in the Eclipse preferences so it pointed to number 2 (-466). After that everything worked fine.

/Martin

Comment: Works for me and my InjelliJ too. Thx.

Comment: Just to add for any IntelliJ users too: After reinstalling like this, I found I had to remove SDK "1.6" in IntelliJ, and then re-add it. In think IntelliJ was caching something from the old 1.6 installation, and I continued to get this error until I re-added the JDK.

Answer (score 6):

[This fix](https://coderwall.com/p/a7szyw/fixing-intellij-idea-after-install-of-yosemite-intellij-idea-quit-unexpectedly) worked for me:

Open your /Applications/{YOUR_IDEA}/Contents/Info.plist file and point to a newer java by changing

```
<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.6*</string>
```

to

```
<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.7+</string>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me too. I couldn't open Android Studio, now I can.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Reinstall java from http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

It worked for me after that.

Comment: Like I wrote, I already did that and it doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

for future users: i faced this issue on netbeans and webstorm. As other said

1. update jdk to http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572
2. and update "~/.bash_profile" file to point to new(updated!) jdk 6 location, by adding (modifying existing) following:

> ```
> export PATH=$PATH:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/bin
> export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home
> ```

Extra note for netbean users: make sure  "/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf" file points to right jdk home if you have previously overriden it:

> netbeans_jdkhome="/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home"

Answer (score 0):

When my mac crashed and was replaced (keeping the hard drive) my Eclipse had a couple issue to work out.  Among them was some of my projects were referring to 1.6 when in fact I had updated to 1.7 and the project needed to refresh this setting.

Right click project->properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add Library->JRE System Library

The System will find the installed JRE and make it the default.  Remove the old JRE and run the application.