# Jmeter is not starting in mac osx 10.10

Tags: macos, jmeter, osx-yosemite, java-6

Im java 6 user and when I try to start jmeter2.12, I try to start using 2 commands which is `$sh jmeter`, `$sh jmeter.sh` and fail. I overcome the below error in both attempts:

```
thushara@Thusharas-MacBook-Pro: ~/Documents/greg/apache-jmeter-2.12/bin $ sh jmeter

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _CGContextSetAllowsAcceleration
  Referenced from: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_65-b14-462.jdk/Contents/Libraries/libawt.jnilib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices

dyld: Symbol not found: _CGContextSetAllowsAcceleration
  Referenced from: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_65-b14-462.jdk/Contents/Libraries/libawt.jnilib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices

jmeter: line 136: 38351 Trace/BPT trap: 5       java $ARGS $JVM_ARGS $JMETER_OPTS -jar "$PRGDIR/ApacheJMeter.jar" "$@"
```

**How should I start the jmeter in new mac osx 10.10?**

Comment: do you have to use Java 6, or can you use a newer version?

Comment: No, I should use java6 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with Java on this new OS.

As per answer on mailing list, reinstall java:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

See also:

- [OSX 10.10 and Eclipse Luna. Own App crashes when started from inside Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26450420/osx-10-10-and-eclipse-luna-own-app-crashes-when-started-from-inside-eclipse)

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall your JDK ? Then run java -version . This issue has nothing to do with JMeter, it is a JAVA/MACOSX issue where java is corrupted.