# how to upgrade my MAC OS X to use newer Java compiler?

Tags: java

This is probably an easy question, but I could not find a clear answer to it by searching on stack overflow. I will delete this thread if its a duplicate. I am on a OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5, and my System.Preferences->java-> general shows that I have version 8 update 66 (build 1.8.0_66-b17). However some code fails due to use of old java compiler.

```
$javac -version (javac 1.6.0_65)
java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-466.1, mixed mode)
```

How can I let my projects use the newest java compiler? (preferably as a systems default)?

Comment: Navigate to java.com, grab the latest JDK.

Comment: @Seva, thats what I have done. The problem is that although I have the newest on my system it still uses the old one.

Comment: If you use Eclipse, you must change the used JDK in its preferences.
This link may help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26450420/osx-10-10-and-eclipse-luna-own-app-crashes-when-started-from-inside-eclipse

Comment: @Claus. Thanks but I am using sublime and sbt for a scala project.

Comment: Nevertheless on OSX you can install and use multiple JDK versions. You have to take care your development system is using the right one

Comment: claus. Thats the core of what I am asking about.

Comment: Use homebrew (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_management_software)) and then you can install any Java version. You can also update packages with just doing 'brew update upgrade'

Comment: Don't use `java.com` - what it offers is just the JRE, not the JDK. Go to where the answer by @Manoj J. tells you to go - to the JDK downloads on Oracle. Load the JDK. You don't need Homebrew or anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After downloading the right jdk/jre @java.com, in your home directory (aka `/home/<your name account>`), add these lines to file `.bash_profile` (create file if don't exist and don't forget to replace `<version>` and change path if needed) :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<version>.jdk/Contents/Home
```

hope this will help you

Comment: @Chobert. I suspect that helps a lot. Do you know how to add it to a a project as a setting too? for instance sbt and scala?

Comment: @stian : Your projects (scala/java...) use by default the java version of the OS. Add the export directive to bash to set this version. For sbt, using intellij, Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > SBT > JVM, and you can override the path to the jdk (by default, sbt use the version of the project, and, by default, the project use the version of the OS).

Answer (score 1):

Download the JDK from Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/ . Make sure you get the OSX version. It has its own installer so installation should be pretty straight forward.